# json load not working in build but works in unity editor

Tags: c#, android, json, unity-game-engine

When I build on Android my json files seems to not load because I dont see data. in unity editor play it works fine. I'm struggling with something thats working on PC but not on Android. Just a path difference I guess but its not easy for a beginner.

here is my code TRY 1:

```
public static JsonData LoadFile(string path)
{
    var fileContents = File.ReadAllText(path);
    var data = JsonMapper.ToObject(fileContents);
    return data;
}

public void QuestionLoader()
{
    // Load the Json file and store its contents in a 'JsonData' variable
    var data = LoadFile(Application.dataPath + "/Resources/json/level1.json");
```

And Here is my try 2 - Based on Unity Manual - https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/StreamingAssets.html:

```
   public static JsonData LoadFile(string path)
{

    var www = new WWW(path);
    return www.text;

    //var fileContents = File.ReadAllText(path);
   // var data = JsonMapper.ToObject(fileContents);
   // return data;
}

public void QuestionLoader()
{
    string path = "";
    // Load the Json file and store its contents 
    #if UNITY_ANDROID

    path = "jar:file://" + Application.dataPath + "!/assets/Levels/level1.json";

    #endif

    #if UNITY_EDITOR

    path = Application.dataPath + "/StreamingAssets/Levels/level1.json";

    #endif
    //
    var data = LoadFile(path);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to load json that already exist in the project from any platform, you have two options:

**1**.Put the Json file in the Resources folder then use `Resources.Load` to read it as a [`TextAsset`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/TextAsset.html). See the end of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44421935/3785314) answer for example.

**2**.Make the json file an AssetBundle then use `WWW.LoadFromCacheOrDownload` to load it.

---

Any of these should work. Once you read the json file, you can copy it to the `Application.persistentDataPath` directly so that you will be able to modify it and save it if needed.

Comment: Nice - Thanks for the help